# Making individual user pages using php html

Tags: php, html, member

I have a register and log in page that uses php scripts and stores them in a mysql data, but when each member logs in theyre brought to the same members page. How can i make it so that each member is brought to their individual page that only they can see?

This is the members log in page

```
 <?PHP
    require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

    if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
    {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
        exit;
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Home page</title>
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/fg_membersite.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='fg_membersite_content'>
    <h2>Home Page</h2>
    Welcome back <?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>!

    <p><a href='change-pwd.php'>Change password</a></p>

    <p><a href='access-controlled.php'>Your products</a></p>
    <br><br><br>
    <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why not show your code for this page?

Comment: What do you mean "the same members page"? Does this not echo the user's name `$fgmembersite->UserFullName();`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using sessions. So when a user logs in. He gets a specific session value for his profile. This session can then be used to bring up specific information for his profile.

**Run something like this on login:**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Require the database file
require 'database.php';

// Fetch session_check value when submit is pressed (lets say it's "johnny")
$fetch = $database->prepare("SELECT session_check FROM user WHERE username = $username");
$fetch->execute();
$fetch_session = $fetch->fetchAll();
$user_session = $fetch_session[0]['session_check'];

// Set session variable
$_SESSION["user"] = $user_session;
?>
```

**Echoing this on the members page would then give me and output of: johnny.**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Require the database file
require 'database.php';

// Bind the session variable to a new variable (you should skip this)
$user_session = $_SESSION["user"];

// Fetch personal profile from database
$fetchtwo = $database->prepare("SELECT username FROM user WHERE session_check = $user_session");
$fetchtwo->execute();
$fetch_info = $fetchtwo->fetchAll();

// Display the username depending on user
echo $fetch_info[0]['username'];
?>
```

Now, presume you have a database with 5 columns. The 5th column name is session_check. Now when you login the value from this column specified by the username used, will be added to the session. When in the members area this exact same session will be used to fetch other information from the same row. This is how you create a dynamic and private profile in PHP.

**Read about this here:**

- [w3schools about sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)
- [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Okay thanks, i got the sessions to work with each user, from here how would i be able to make it so that if they filled in a form when it got added to the database only they could view it?

Comment: @Budgey Okai, so what is your session? the username? A specified hash? or? You need to fetch the information from the database using a query with for example: `WHERE username = $_SESSION["username"]`. I recommand taking a look into PDO and how to select a single column depending on a variable :) Take a look on one of my projects on GitHub, it's far from a finished safe version, but explains it pretty well: https://github.com/ggjersund/Wewent/blob/register/sidebar.php

Comment: I have it so that the user logs in, it creates a session. They fill in a form i tried adding this line <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="$_SESSION['id_user']" /> to add id_user from the session that the user created when they fill in the form, but in my table on phpmyadmin the id_user just says $_SESSION['id_user'] and not the actual user.

Comment: @Budgey I recommand that you look over my files at GitHub. How I create the form, post it in the database, create a session, and then how I enter the members.php. Show's you the basics.

Comment: @Budgey Hi, has there been any progress lately? If not please keep asking otherwise I would love if you accepted my answer. I will add some improvements.

Comment: yeah ive been able to set user sessions so that each member has a unique homepage thanks a lot for you help .

Comment: @Budgey Hi, would love if you accepted my answer so it's easy for others to find out how to fix similar problems. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't a specific member page just really just the same page with different that is uniq to a member. I think how you could start is by figuring out how to manage the member data which will actually you to create 'different' login pages. You could have data stored in a database. Then you have a php script that reads the data for a member any then creates their login page. So, basically, you still only need one script, but it uses a database.

Comment: I have a database for each user, im wondering how to do the script that displays the users the same home page but individual php code, so that when they click on access-controlled.php it is unique to each user.

Comment: What does access-controlled.php do? Why would you want to have to go to the trouble to have different script for each user. That's not efficient. Unless you have a good reason for it then why not place the data into a database?

Comment: It shows their "products". What would be the best way so that if user A signs in he only see products for him and if user B signs in he only sees products for him?

Comment: Again, a database is the perfect solution. A database is designed specifically to handle data the are unique to some entity, in this case it would be a member. I would recommend learning about database basics.